# jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js clashes with bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

At present I am working above mentioned datetimepickers. jQuery datetime picker fights with bootstrap datetimepicker.

Jquery datetimer pciker sample code:

```
$('#start-date').datetimepicker({
            onShow: function(ct){
              this.setOptions({
                minDate: new Date()
              });
            },
            timepicker: true,
)};
```

Bootstrap datetimer pciker sample code:

```
 $('#end-date').datetimepicker({

    )};
```

Here The problem is They use the same function called datetimepcker(). so that They have a fight each other. please help me overcome this problem.

Comment: The question is why would you want to use two different plugins with the same name and initialization that essentially do the exact same thing?

Comment: the -correct- way to resolve this is to pick one to use and not include the other.

Comment: in my project the client uses two datetimepickers for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the codes in different files and include the respective files in the respective html.

e.g you can write the jquery datetime picker in jquery_datetime_picker.js and bootstrap in bootstrap_datetime_picker.js and include these files in the respective html files using `java_script_include_tag`

also include bootstrap in bootstrap_datetime_picker.js file

Comment: i just renamed the file names but it is not working for me. give me any another suggestion.

Comment: can you display the code, the files. it would be easier for understanding

Comment: it is large. sorry to say , I can not display it.